# Auto Change MyISAM to Inno DB

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I am beginner in web hosting. I have some site which are created by php/codeigniter.. Today All custom sites (created by codeigniter) are showing these msg

Error Number: 1286

Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'

Don't understand why this happened.. Give me idea why this happened and how to solve this issue.

Comment: To clarify: Yesterday, these were all working InnoDB tables? The title sounds like you want to change current MyISAM tables to InnoDB. If I'm right, youi most certainly do not want to do that - you want to be able to use the InnoDB engine again. Any known changes to the servers in question that could have broken the existing code?

Comment: See mysql's error log -- it may give more details.